# killall, excluding specific process IDs

Tags: bash, kill

Okay, so I've had a case come up lately whereby I'm ending up with duplicate processes that I don't need. Now obviously I'm trying to figure out why I'm ending up with duplicates, but in the mean time I'm wondering if there's a better way to clear them.

Currently I'm running `killall <process name>` and then manually triggering a single instance of the process. However, what I'd really like to do is run a `killall` that somehow ignores a specific process ID.

Actually, the process in question is a bash-script with a unique name, so I can easily kill all duplicates of it with `killall`, and I'd like to edit it so that, when launched, it will kill all other instances of itself, except for the current process (`$$`), in case that makes it any easier.

I know I could probably do this with `ps` and `grep` and feed the results into `kill` after filtering out the current process ID, but is this the only way, or is there a better option (besides preventing the duplicates in the first place, which I still haven't figured out yet)?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `pgrep` instead, it will give you a list of the processes PIDs with the given name, so you can do something like `pgrep java` and get the list easier than with ps and grep

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you are looking for ?

```
kill $(ps aux | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v <ur pid>)
```

Comment: Did you mean `grep -v "$$"` to go at the end there? That could perhaps work with a suitable filter at the beginning. For example, to integrate @Konato_K's answer perhaps this: `pgrep "$(basename "$0")" | grep -v "$$"` would be sufficient? It probably needs to go through `xargs` before being fed to `kill` though?